# Is "between A to B" considered good grammar?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I looked at ["Between A and B vs from A to B"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-vs-from-a-to-b), but it didn't mention a third variation I've been hearing more often, recently.

Even on the Australian national broadcaster, the ABC, I've heard statements by reporters like

> The cost was estimated to be between A to B dollars.

Have the rules of grammar changed, or is this as ungrammatical as I think it is?

Comment: Call them up and tell them to stop using bad grammar.  I hate this construction and want to see it stamped out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not right to use *between A to B*, or *from A and B* for that matter, though the former is a common error.

Intuitively, *to* suggests motion just like *from*, while *between* is a reference to two objects and should be paired with *and*.

Comment: I agree, except that *to* doesn't suggest motion to me: it suggests a *range* of values. We can say something is *between* the endpoints of a range, but not *between a range*. It seem incomplete.

Comment: yes, I see from your Network Profile that you're more of a mathematician than a programmer. I see a range as a single object. Both are valid viewpoints, I think.

Answer (score 6):

I would say

> ... between A and B.

but

> ... from A to B.

Answer (score 2):

It's *between A and B* or *between Bs*.

> The dog crawled between us and lay down at our feet.
>   Traffic was at a standstill between exits 12 and 14.
>   They had drunk between them a bottle of Chianti.

The NOAD reports some notes about the usage of *between*.

> *Between* is used in speaking of only two things, people, etc.: "We must choose between two equally unattractive alternatives." *Among* is used for collective and undefined relations of usually three or more: "Agreement on landscaping was reached among all the neighbors." But where there are more than two parties involved, *between* may be used to express one-to-one relationships of pairs within the group or the sense 'shared by': "There is close friendship between the members of the club."

Comment: I agree with this, too. *Between a [range of values]* is unsatisfactory because the programmer in me identifies a *range* as a single thing, and, as the NOAD report states, you can only be *between* two things.

Comment: This isn't totally true, as [Mignon Fogarty](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/between-versus-among) points out. 'Between', not 'among', would be chosen as a broadened usage for say 'somewhere between Lincoln, Nottingham and Grantham'.

Answer (score 1):

If it is commonly used in Australian English, then it is grammatical in that dialect.

That said, it will likely sound odd in pretty much any other dialect, and may lead your audience to ask whether you have made an error.

Comment: My impression is that it is becoming more and more common *here* -- but it may be that because it grates, I'm sensitised to it. I'm not likely to adopt that pattern of speech.