# When is "between" inclusive and when exclusive?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, range-inclusion

It seems that the exact meaning of *between* is very tied to its specific usage. What should I assume in a general situation about the inclusivity of *between*? Consider:

- "Pick a number between 1 and 10." Most people would consider *between* inclusive.
- "How many numbers are there between 1 and 10?" Most people would consider *between* exclusive, i.e. 8 to be the correct answer.

Could the meaning of the word *between* have something to do with the grammatical structure of the sentence in which it is used?

Comment: Related: [“Between A and B” or “from A to B”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-or-from-a-to-b), ["Add number between x … y"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-number-between-x-y)

Comment: Your "most people" sample is how large?

Comment: Not only the includedness or otherwise of your bounds is problematic (though that is a matter of definition). Most mathematicians would ask you to define which set of numbers you are talking about when you ask "How many numbers are there between 1 and 10?"

Comment: For discrete objects such as finite lists of integers, "between" typically by default conveys inclusivity of the min- and max- imum.  For one-word twosided exclusivity (i.e., not including the endpoints, as in open intervals of continuous data ranges such as a segment of the number-line), you could swap 'between' for 'inbetween'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no rule as to when *between* can be considered inclusive or exclusive, and the grammatical structure of the relevant sentence would not affect this.

You may be able to make deductions or assumptions from the subject and context of the sentence itself or surrounding sentences, but that would be *only assumptions*.

If the question of inclusion or exclusion were critical, the only way to determine what was intended would be to ask the author or speaker.

Personally, I would say that *very strictly* the limits of "between" are exclusive. But you cannot tell how any particular person uses it, and therefore, the only appropriate answer to your question is: "If in doubt, ask!"

**Addendum (post-acceptance):**
The fact that "between" is strictly *exclusive* of the limits can be illustrated by considering its use when referring to physical objects. For example, you might refer to:

> the gap/space *between* two parked vehicles
>   the path *between* the river and the road

In such cases the 'limits' are the vehicles, river and road: "between" *does not include* the vehicles, river or road, but refers only to the 'area' *within* those 'limits', namely the gap/space or path.
Likewise, "between 1 and 10" excludes the 'limits' 1 and 10, and includes only the 'items *within* those limits, namely 2 to 9.

Comment: Counter point, and where the ambiguity comes from:  "Pick a number between 3 and 4"   Trick question, or one with two, clear choices?

Comment: 3.001, 3.01, 3.1 ... 3.999999

IMO I've heard people say "pick a number *from* 1 *to* 10", which I think would be inclusive. If people say between 3 and 4, I don't think you have an integer option.

Comment: @TrevorD: On the other hand, the phrase "Between you and me" clearly *includes* both "you" and "me" (and indeed excludes everyone else). So your answer is correct to say there is no general rule :-)

Comment: @psmears Can you (or anyone) give an example sentence where "between you and me" is inclusive? I'm curious if I can come up with a way to show that it is _actually_ exclusive.

Comment: @akinuri See 1. [(just) between you and me](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just-between-you-and-me) "used to tell someone that what you are about to say should be kept secret"; 2. [(just) between you and me](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/between+you+and+me) "What is going to be or has been said should not be told to anyone else. This phrase is usually said along with information that needs to be kept secret."  These are clearly instances where "between you and me" **is inclusive** - and also **exclusive** of anyone else.

Comment: @akinuri Further examples of "between you and me" being **exclusive** are: let's keep a distance of 2 metres between you & me; there is a door between you & me'; etc..

Comment: Hmm, so it seems its first/literal meaning (about physical world) is exclusive, but when used for other reasons, it might be inclusive. If we were to be really technical, I'd translate "(just) between you and me" as "there are things that we keep to ourselves, that we don't share with others; this is one of them (or this is among them)". So "between" here has no position value... I was writing a `between(min, max)` function, and wasn't sure if I should make the `min` and `max` inclusive by default.

Comment: "between you and me" is exclusive, as it is a subject existing outside the two "endpoints". The secret isn't "you" or "me", but it exists as a coupling "between" us. Between has been corrupted to be inclusive.

Comment: Excellent discussion. I'm trying to come up with a clear term for an inclusive date range. Like, from Oct 1, 2020 to Dec 31, 2020, inclusive. I was using "between" like "between Oct 1, 2020 and Dec 31, 2020" but I realize now that there is a lot of ambiguity with whether that infers inclusivity or not. After reading this answer, I'm thinking "within" is a much clearer word choice here. i.e. "within Oct 1, 2020 and Dec 31, 2020". Not perfect, but I think clearer. Having written all that, maybe the clearest still is "from Oct 1, 2020 to Dec 31, 2020"...

Answer (score 9):

As TrevorD says, there's no reliable way to tell unless the speaker actually *says* "inclusive". In US English there's the useful form "One through ten" to indicate that it's an inclusive range, and it's making some headway in British use. That's one American language import that I don't mind, because it's so useful.

Comment: Wouldn't "one to ten" be the normal British phrase?

Comment: "One to ten" can have the same ambiguity as "between" - we still have to say "one to ten, inclusive" or "one to ten, exclusive".

Comment: I would say that, in British English, "*from* 1 to 10" (as in "pick a number *from* 1 to 10") would normally be interpreted as inclusive

Answer (score 0):

Like in the example above: which is the distance from the river to the road, it surely must be exclusive (unless you are on the wrong side of the river, in which case you might be asked if you want to include the width of the river). So from....to also requires context. Right?