# When people say "between ... and ...", are the two boundary number included?

Tags: meaning, phrases

For example, when we say "the number of items is between 8 and 13", does this include the two boundary numbers, 8 and 13?

Comment: In regular English apart from mathematical discussions the endpoints are usually meant to be included.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question that was satisfactorily answered previously. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118402/when-is-between-inclusive-and-when-exclusive

Comment: Yes. "The number of items is between 7.9 and 13.1" is distinctly off-register. And usually, 'between 1000 and 1500' when there are 997 or 1506 would be assumed to be the normal approximate use of language in everyday language, but a false statement in mathspeak.