# "a to b" vs "a through b"

Tags: ambiguity, time

Is there a fundamental difference between 'a to b' and 'a through b'? In my specific case, 'a' and 'b' are dates.

Is one inclusive of 'b' and the other ... not inclusive? Ambiguous?

Comment: They're both potentially ambiguous, but *A **through** B* is more *likely* to include B than *A **to** B*.

Comment: A better way to avoid ambiguity is to use "inclusive", e.g. "28 Apr to 4 May inclusive".

Comment: The earlier comments are useful. My impression is of a *discrete* path from 'a to b' versus a *continuous* one from 'a through b'. In other words, the latter statement is like an integral in calculus with a potentially infinite number of stopping points while the former has an inherently finite number, perhaps only two points, a and b.

Comment: Does this answer your question, mankoff? [Is there an alternative for the word "between" that implies "inclusive" without ambiguity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/576280/is-there-an-alternative-for-the-word-between-that-implies-inclusive-without) And/or [_between a and b_ or _from a to b_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-or-from-a-to-b)