# Between 5 and 10 means: “5 and 10” or “6 and 9”?

Tags: meaning, differences

> Please enter between 5 and 10 characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Between A and B" or "from A to B"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-or-from-a-to-b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means 5 to 10 and includes the 5 and 10 as well.

In some cases, people use the term 'inclusive' to emphasize that it includes both extremes. But even without it, it means the same.