# When to write number and word combinations?

Tags: grammar, numbers

I have two puzzles here. Whether to use 'and' or 'to' AND should it be 100,00 or 100 thousand.

(a) There used to be 10 million but it is estimated that numbers have dropped to between 50 **to** 100 **thousand**.
(b) There used to be 10 million but it is estimated that numbers have dropped to between 50 **to** **100,000**.

OR use 'and'
(c) There used to be 10 million but it is estimated that numbers have dropped to between 50 **and** 100 thousand.
(d) There used to be 10 million but it is estimated that numbers have dropped to between 50 **and** 100,000.

Comment: Always: *between* (number) **and** (number);  without *between* (with optional *from*) use (number) **to** (number). HTH.

Comment: This Q may be better on [ell.se]

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Between A and B" or "from A to B"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/between-a-and-b-or-from-a-to-b)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

> between 50 and 100 thousand

or

> (from) 50 to 100 thousand (without between).

Because you're using *dropped to*, it might be preferable to avoid the initial *from* and just say *dropped to 50 to 100 thousand* instead of the more clumsy *dropped to from 50 to 100 thousand*.

50 to 100000 could literally mean anything between the two-digit number 50 and six-digit number 100000, although I believe context may disambiguate this. To avoid ambiguity altogether use

> 50 and 100 thousand

or

> 50000 and 100000